# No SIM detected after installing CM13 nightly on Galaxy S III (AT&T) SGH-i747

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, custom-roms

After CM13 was installed on my Samsung Galaxy S III, I faced unstable camera and browser and whenever I attempted to turn the cellular network on, I received the following error:

> Unfortunately, the process.com.android,phone has stopped

I put the SIM to another cellphone and didn't get the earlier mentioned error. I asked AT&T to provide me a new cellphone and got the same error after I inserted the SIM card onto the device.

What I already **did**:

- I **did** wipe `phone`, `SIM` and `contact storage` cache and data in two different ways,
- I **did** delete `Phone folder` and `Sim Toolkit`
- I **did** dial and type `*#*#3646633#*#*`,
- I **did** disable `Automatic Time Zone`
- I **did** factory reset the phone many times,
- I **did** flash it again with following list:

  1. cm-13.0-20160402-NIGHTLY-d2att
  2. twrp-3.0.1-0-d2att.img
  3. modem_CWM_I747UCDMG2
  4. Odin_v3.09

I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly advice me on what I can do to get my cellphone running back again.

My device is Samsung Galaxy S III (AT&T), device model `SGH-i747`.